# Custom template(transclusion without ng-content) for list component in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, transclusion

I have a list component which shows only names. list component should be able to take custom template which will be given by user.

List Component

```
import {Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  template: `<p>This is List</p>
     <ul>
       <li *ngFor="#i of data"><div class='listItem'>{{i.name}}</div></li>
    </ul>`
})
export class MyList implements OnInit{ 
    data: Array<any> = [{name: 'John', age: 26},{name: 'Kevin', age: 26},  {name:'Simmons', age:26}];
}
```

My Requirement

```
<my-list>
   <div>{{i.name}}-{{i.age}}</div> //user should be able to provide custom template like this
</my-list>
```

I tried this with ng-content but it throws error. In angular 1 same thing used to work with transcluded content. do we have any alternative of manual transclusion in angular 2 and if not then how could we implement this feature in angular2.

Here is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ukmNJ2aRzLYxDganDg5W?p=preview)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use ngForTemplate, I've created PrimeNG DataList and many other DataComponents using this technique and it works great. Demo;

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datalist

Code;

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/datalist/datalist.ts

In your component, define a templateRef with contentchild;

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef;
```

Your template becomes;

```
template: `<p>This is List</p>
     <ul>
       <template ngFor [ngForOf]="data" [ngForTemplate]="itemTemplate"></template>
    </ul>`
```

So that your users can define content like;

```
<my-list>
   <template #anything>
        <div>{{anything.i.name}}-{{anything.i.age}}</div>
   </template>
</my-list>
```

Comment: Great example! Thanks for sharing! Works fine with Angular 4 as well! :)

Comment: Thank you.  <template> is deprecated in angular 4 and will be removed in 5, use <ng-template> instead:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-features-10
https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/bf8eb41

Answer (score 1):

There was a question regarding this in the past (see [Use content of component template in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353103/use-content-of-component-template-in-angular-2/36354717#36354717)) and this doesn't seem to be supported.

There are two things here:

- When you provide an input template for the component, your `i` is variable is evaluated against the current component and not `my-list` one. If you want to use its properties you must do something like that:

  ```
  <my-list #myList>
    <div>{{myList.i.name}}-{{myList.i.age}}</div> //user should be able to provide custom template like this
  </my-list>
  ```
- The other problem is the ability to use `ng-content` within a loop and it's not supported. I think that we could add an issue for this...

Here is a the plunkr I used for my tests: https://plnkr.co/edit/a06vVP?p=preview.

Comment: this is perfect for properties but still we can't use custom template. can't we somehow get reference of content of template and clone it for ngFor like angular1?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a short interesting guide which shows you how to build such a list-component with custom-template 
[here](https://dev-plaza.com/list-component-custom-html-elements-selection-highlighting).