# Angular2 Directive with scope

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

Directives in Angular2 do not have "scopes", while Components do. But in my case I need Directive to create a scope. Look at my App component - it has an HTML template, and ANYWHERE on any element the `foo` directive could appear. This should grab some date from service and assign it to the Element.

In Angular1 it was very easy... Directives could have its own scope. But in Angular 2 I cannot find any (even dirty) way to achieve that.

It looks like a simple task, doesn't it?

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[foo]'
})
class FooDirective {
  @Input()
  public id:string;

  public bar;

  constructor() {
     this.bar = 'This is the "bar" I actually need. It is taken from DB let's say..' + this.id;
  }
}




@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
     <div foo id="2">
       This is random content 1: {{bar}}
     </div>

     <div foo id="2">
       This is random content 2: {{bar}}
     </div>
  `,
  directives: [FooDirective]
})
class App {
  bar:string = 'This should be ignored, I need "bar" to be set from directive!';
}

bootstrap(App);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like that leveraging a local variable that would reference the applied directive:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `
    <div foo id="2" #dir1="foo">
      This is random content 1: {{dir1.bar}}
    </div>

    <div foo id="2" #dir2="foo">
      This is random content 2: {{dir2.bar}}
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [FooDirective]
})
class App {
  bar:string = 'This should be ignored, I need "bar" to be set from directive!';
}
```

In your case `bar` is evaluated using properties of the current component, the `App` one.

**Edit** (following the @yurzui's comment)

You need to add an `exportAs` property in your directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[foo]',
  exportAs: 'foo'
})
class FooDirective {
  (...)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But let's say I'm creating "helper" directive for our designers, and I said them "add foo on any element, and it will grab some data from database".. And I don't need to add "extra work" for them.. (I already done this tool with angular 1, so they will not like my new tool with "more work for them"

Comment: Don't forget to add exportAs: 'foo' within metadata directive.

Comment: Also I think there is limit in one template for those "local variables". But our templates are quite big

Comment: I understand well your approach! That said, I'm not sure that it's possible with Angular2 directive. I guess that you could do something with components (with an attribute selector) and a template element. Something like this: `<div foo><template>something</template></div>`. This answer could give you ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531503/custom-templatetransclusion-without-ng-content-for-list-component-in-angular2.

Comment: `ng-content` is also supported but variables are resolved in the component that provides this content...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier your hint with <template> tag give me idea to try something like *foo. I think I have to take a look how *ngFor is made - it has some local variables (like index, even, odd). Thanks for you hint

Comment: @ArūnasSmaliukas ngFor leverages embedded views with the `ViewContainerRef` class...

Answer (score 0):

What do mean when you say that components do have scope?

My understanding is that there is no shared object (or prototypal inheritance) between components. But I think that is what you are looking for -- you want FooDirective and App to share the same (scope) object, correct? If so, I don't think there is anything equivalent in Angular 2.

---

I doubt you'll like this, but the best I could come up with (that is different from @Thierry's approach) is to use the `div` as the "shared object" (rather than the directive).  The directive uses HostBinding to save the value to a data attribute on the `div`, then the component retrieves that value in the template, using a local variable to get a reference to the `div`/shared object:

```ts
import {Component, Directive, Input, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[foo]'})
class FooDirective {
  @Input() id:string;
  @HostBinding('attr.data-bar') bar;
  ngOnInit() {
     this.bar = 'This is "bar" I actually need. It is taken from DB lets say...' + this.id;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `{{title}}<p>
    <div #div1 foo id="2">
      This is random content 1: {{div1.getAttribute('data-bar')}}
    </div>`,
  directives: [FooDirective]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = `Angular - RC.1`;
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K6S10Ynp8oexgwLz4beq?p=preview)</kbd>

I like @Thierry's approach better than what I show above, but I figured I would post what I was toying around with anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still try to make "less work" for my company designers. I mean they already are using my directive from Angular 1 and I said them "Add 'foo' on any element and you will have some magick value in `{{bar}}`". I cannot say to them "I have made better tool with angular 2 but now you will have to add more work to make the same result..." And I still believe that it is possible to make it with Angular 2.. At the moment I'm trying with structural directives (*foo)